# ¿Cómo puedo poner el Android Studio para trabajar offline?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, gradle, layout, build.gradle

Mi Android Studio no me carga los layouts (uso la pantalla dividida, código y diseño), antes era después de un tiempo de haberlo abierto, ahora lo hace apenas lo abro.

Yo supongo que fue por conectar mi cuenta de google. Hace poco cerré la sesión, así que supuse que ese fue el problema.

Así que vi la siguiente solución y quise implementarla pero no encuentro el 'Offline work'.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859572/10783826

Mi ventana se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no me deja trabajar.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola @JhonnyL esa opción ya no aplica, ahora la puedes ver desde la opción "Gradle", agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las últimas versiones de Android Studio el "modo offline" es controlado mediante el plugin de Gradle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Android Studio lo puedes encontrar del lado derecho donde se muestra la opción "Gradle", das clic para expander el panel y ahí puedes ver la opción para activar/desactivar el "modo offline".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si activas el icono [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] trabajaras en "modo offline".

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Recuerda si alguna respuesta soluciono el problema planteado @JhonnyL marcala como solución , revisar [tour].,saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ir a File -> Settings.

Y luego abrir 'Build,Execution,Deployment'. Luego abre

Build Tools -> Gradle

Luego check -> modo ofline a la derecha .

Presiona el botón ok.

Luego Reconstruye el proyecto .

Comment: Disculpa pero no encuentro 'Build Tools' dentro de 'Build,Execution,Deployment'.

Comment: Esto ya no aplica, ya no existe esa opción.